# Twilio Programmable SMS npm package not sending SMS from Safari

Tags: reactjs, safari, twilio, sms

I am currently using the react js web application and I am using the Twilio Programmable SMS service which is working fine with Chrome and Firefox, but when I try to send SMS from the Safari browser then it says "Network Error".

Below is my sample code for SMS:

```
const twilio = require('twilio'); 
var client = new twilio(config.TWILIO.accountSid, config.TWILIO.authToken);
var twilioObj = {
    body: messageBody,
    from: config.TWILIO.fromNumber,
    to: '+91' + toNumber
};
if (medialLink !== undefined) {
    twilioObj = {
        body: messageBody,
        from: config.TWILIO.fromNumber,
        mediaUrl: [medialLink],
        to: '+91' + toNumber
    };
}
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    client.messages.create(twilioObj)
        .then(function (message) {
            alert('message sent')
            resolve({
                status: true,
                message_id: message.sid
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            alert('error' + error)
            resolve({
                status: false,
            });
        });
});
```

Anyone had the same problem?